# Subdomain and Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, subdomain

I have an Zend Framework application with a subdomain that works well in my local development environment. Now I'm trying to put it on the live location, in a shared hosting environment. I have made the subdomain in DirectAdmin.

This is the default content of the .htaccess in public_html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I have removed the folder public_html/subdomain because I want that everything goes through index.php. But the problem is that if I go to subdomain.example.com I get a 500 Internal Server Error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a host-specific issue. Typically, if you were running your own Apache server, you would create a VirtualHost directive that would point your subdomain to your application's public folder.

I know some hosts will treat each domain / subdomain as it's separate folder. If your host is expecting you to have a `public_html/subdomain` folder, why not try making the subdomain folder a symbolic link to your application's public folder?

```
ln -s /path/to/zf/public/folder /path/to/public_html/subdomain/folder
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, is it possible to do this in htaccess or do I need SSH access

Comment: You would likely need SSH access, or an FTP program that can handle creating symbolic links.

Comment: ok, and what if I don't have SSH access. Are there also possibilities with rewriterules in .htaccess